# Cron job from mysql and send an email with results

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I have a ubuntu box hosted and need to setup a cron job for executing a stored procedure and sending the results via email to one address once a week. How can I do this?

I am using Mailgun

Answer (score 0):

According to [cron manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/cron.8.html):

```
When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of 
the crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable
in the crontab, if such exists)
```

So you should use this command in order to modify `crontab` configuration file:

```
crontab -e
```

This will open `/etc/crontab` file and, according to [crontab manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/crontab.1.html):

```
The -e option is used to edit the  current  crontab  using  the  editor
specified  by  the  VISUAL  or EDITOR environment variables.  After you
exit  from  the  editor,  the  modified  crontab  will   be   installed
automatically. If neither of the environment variables is defined, then
the default editor /usr/bin/editor is used.
```

Add this line in order to choose user mailed with output of your script:

```
MAILTO="userMailed"
```

You should not need this if `userMailed` is same as user who runs `crontab -e`.

In order to run your script weekly you should add another line. To do this, there are many different way such as:

```
5 4 * * sun   /path/to/your/script
```

this will run at 5 after 4 every sunday, or:

```
 @weekly      /path/to/your/script
```

this will run once a week, same as "0 0 * * 0".

You can choose your best options following [crontab manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/crontab.1.html).

Save your change, this will automatically install your cron job.

Comment: Can you use a different mail service to send emails?

Comment: I guess you should setup your system for this. Here is a useful link on [Setting Up Your System To Use E-Mail](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/mail-setup.html)

Comment: I found these links [Set up Postfix with Mailgun for reliable e-mail delivery](http://www.jamroom.net/brian/documentation/guides/1312/set-up-postfix-with-mailgun-for-reliable-e-mail-delivery) and [How to setup Postfix with a Mailgun SMTP relay when using multiple domains](https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/28/t/3897)